# Can I simulate a Data Transfer Object in RAP application?

Tags: rest, abap, cds

I'm trying to use the [Restful ABAP Programming model](https://help.sap.com/viewer/fc4c71aa50014fd1b43721701471913d/201909.001/en-US) (RAP) to cover the following use-case:

1. Data is received with field a, field b, field c and field d
2. Logic is executed to transform the inbound structure to the db structure (field x and y)
3. Data is saved
4. After save further actions are executed

Is this even possible? Seems like the projection view must be a subset of the db fields. I couldn't find a way to define additional inbound fields, or even map one field name to another.

Is it correct that RAP can only really expose CRUD for the very same CDS fields that are refering to DB fields?

Answer (score 1):

did you try adding dummy fields which you want to inbound ?

```
{
   key a, b, c, d,
   cast(' ' as abap.char(n)) as x,
   cast(' ' as abap.char(n)) as y
 }
```

so you can retrieve a,b,c,d and process the logic and send back x,y and do the rest of the action in behaviour implementation.

Is it correct that RAP can only really expose CRUD for the very same CDS fields that are refering to DB fields?- Yes that is understanding in terms of payload but in ABAP layer you can determine few other fields any ways.

Comment: Yes, sadly `cast(' ' as abap.char(3)) as y` comes up as `Field Y contains a not supported expression` in the projection view. I can add it to the "normal" view and try it out. Just hoped there would be a better way, since the inbound fields are service specific (so projection), but then pollute the business object itself. I'll try it out and see how save behaves with that approach

Comment: Though then again I've the problem that field a and b must be read-only as they are calculated by the other attributes. But in other services that must not be the case and they should be provided directly. Hm

Comment: you can make the fields read only by adding the annotation @ObjectModel.readOnly: true/false , this generally works with BOPF based service not sure on the RAP, maybe you can give it a try.